# how to split a file using python in key and values (or any other format)

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, python-3.x, machine-learning

Lets say I have a doc file which contains the following

> **Therapeutic Focus and Assessment :**  Describe the (1) types of interventions (such as pharmacologic, surgical, preventive, lifestyle,
> self-care) and (2) administration and intensity of the intervention
> (including dosage, strength, duration, frequency).
>
> **Follow-up and Outcomes :** Please describe the clinical course of this case including all follow-up visits as well as (1) intervention
> modification, interruption, or discontinuation, and the reasons; (2)
> adherence to the intervention and how this was assessed;
>
> **Discussion :**  Please describe the strengths and limitations of this case report including case management, and the scientific and
> medical literature related to this case report.

*In this file I want to separate each heading and its content. Which means I will have 3 headings and 3 contains. I am thinking to make headings as a key and content as its value. How I can use regex to filter this information.*

***Little change in file structure : (additional question)***

> **Therapeutic Focus and Assessment :**  Describe the (1) types of interventions (such as pharmacologic, surgical, preventive, lifestyle,
> self-care) and (2) administration and intensity of the intervention
> (including dosage, strength, duration, frequency).
>
> **Discussion :**
>
> Please describe the strengths and limitations of this case report including case > management, and the scientific. **Health :** medical literature related to this > case report.

*If I will have this king of file where content in first paragraph is in line and in second paragraph it has a line gap. One more additional section is also included in the same paragraph. In that case how I will split?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with splitting based on characters rather then regex.

```
String document = "Header: blah blah \n Header: blah blah"

String[] sections = document.split("\n");
String[] headers = new String[sections.length];
String[] bodies = new String[sections.length];;

for(int i = 0; i < sections.length; i++){
      headers[i] = sections[i].split(":")[0];
      bodies[i] = sections[i].substring(headers[i].length() + 2);
}
```

The same split method works on regex patterns if you have something more complex to divide by then a carriage return and a ":", but by the looks of it this may work for you.

Comment: Hi Stef2i, Please see my post. In this I have added one more file structure. If I will have this file structure then how I will split?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I didn't see your message. Some how you have to make some assumption on the format of your file. Do you only use a ":" near headings? Is there anyway when you import your file that you can save what is bold or not and break it that way? There has to be some pattern that defines what a heading is to be able to split it.

If it is based on ":" then you could make a reg expression that checks for a full stop, a carriage return, or the start of the file, followed by a string, followed by a ":" and break it that way. If this is what you need I can help you with it.

Comment: Hi Stef2i. I just figured out that issue. Thank you so much for your help.